How do I solve module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'. Error while using MICE?
Here's my code
1
2
Here's some data
3 - data sample
Here's knn imputation result
4 - knn imputation
Hi, I'm a beginner in machine learning. While filling in the missing values in the data using MICE, this error occured. I tried to find other's example of this error to solve mine, but I can't.
Plus) I tried iterative imputation & knn(n_neighbors = 2) using the same data before, and they filled all missing_values with 23.725771. Is this normal?
